# Send and receive emails with smtp server

Tags: node.js, laravel

I have a website hosted on goddady . it comes with smtp server to send and receive emails through the server

I want to make a script to connect with that server on the info email "info@myserver.com" and read/send emails by the script .

Is there any idea to do that ?

with laravel or nodejs , but I prefer to be in laravel

thanks

Comment: smtp is for sending mails
pop3 / imap you can recaive mails

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#sending-mail

Comment: so how can I view the received mails ?

Comment: You can use phpmailer for use smtp for send emails.it required username and password after set smtp on your server(it needs some configs on web config file).and for read emails you can use functions of php for imap or use packages like mailparser.

Comment: Look at this or other examples https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap